# Truffle doesn't create the file initial migration.js automatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, migration, version, truffle

I m trying to migrate a smart contract on ganache but I notice that the file initial migration.js is not created automatically.

Launching the comand truffle version I get this:

```
Truffle v5.7.1 (core: 5.7.1)
Ganache v7.6.0
Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js)
Node v16.18.0
Web3.js v1.8.1
```

What is wrong? Is it a version problem? Thanks in advance

I opened a terminal using visual studio code. I expect that the file initial migration.js is created automatically

Answer (score 1):

Annoying thing. You may try:

```
truffle unbox
```

Comment: I did as you suggested and copied the files into a project created using `truffle init .`